# Powerquery group rows based on cell value

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have quite a large dataset where I need to compile a column based on its cell values.

an example of the data is below:

[image]

I'm trying to:

- Merge all rows in the column 'Product' that only have the value 'AccountsA'
- The numerical values need to be summed for 'AccountsA' when merged
- The 'Product_Type' values differ and can be replaced with 'A' when merged for 'AccountsA'

My first thought was to use an if statement but I don't know if this is possible when grouping in powerquery and I'm struggling to find any examples online.

The outcome I'm trying to achieve is shown below (using the above example):

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with this as Table1:

[image]

This code...

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Product", type text}, {"Channel", type text}, {"Product_Type", type text}, {"Total Offered Net", Int64.Type}, {"Total Offered Inc", Int64.Type}, {"Total Handled", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Product"}, {{"Channel", each [Channel]{0}}, {"Product_Type", each [Product_Type]{0}}, {"Total Offered Net", each List.Sum([Total Offered Net]), type nullable number}, {"Total Offered Inc", each List.Sum([Total Offered Inc]), type nullable number}, {"Total Handled", each List.Sum([Total Handled]), type nullable number}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Grouped Rows", each [Product] = "AccountsA"),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Product] <> "AccountsA")),
    #"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({#"Filtered Rows1", #"Filtered Rows"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Appended Query",{{"Product", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

...gives me this result:

[image]